# Firebaseauth onComplete not firing

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm creating a firebase registration activity as part of a coding exercise and can't get successfully complete a sign-in. It's worth noting that I had to update the dependencies to the suggested versions to get the project to build, as the ones provided by the exercise didn't work.

Project Gradle:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

App gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.andrewedgar.theo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Activity (createFirebaseUser method):

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Constants
    public static final String CHAT_PREFS = "ChatPrefs";
    public static final String DISPLAY_NAME_KEY = "username";

    // TODO: Add member variables here:
    // UI references.
    private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
    private AutoCompleteTextView mUsernameView;
    private EditText mPasswordView;
    private EditText mConfirmPasswordView;

    // Firebase instance variables

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.register_email);
        mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_password);
        mConfirmPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_confirm_password);
        mUsernameView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.register_username);

        // Keyboard sign in action
        mConfirmPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (id == R.integer.register_form_finished || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                    attemptRegistration();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        // TODO: Get hold of an instance of FirebaseAuth


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    }

    // Executed when Sign Up button is pressed.
    public void signUp(View v) {
        attemptRegistration();
    }

    private void attemptRegistration() {

        // Reset errors displayed in the form.
        mEmailView.setError(null);
        mPasswordView.setError(null);

        // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
        String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

        boolean cancel = false;
        View focusView = null;

        // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password) || !isPasswordValid(password)) {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
            focusView = mPasswordView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        // Check for a valid email address.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = mEmailView;
            cancel = true;
        } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
            focusView = mEmailView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (cancel) {
            // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
            // form field with an error.
            focusView.requestFocus();
        } else {
            // TODO: Call create FirebaseUser() here

        }
    }

    private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
        // You can add more checking logic here.
        return email.contains("@");
    }

    private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
        //TODO: Add own logic to check for a valid password (minimum 6 characters)

        String confirmPassword = mConfirmPasswordView.getText().toString();
        return confirmPassword.equals(password) && password.length() >4;
    }

    // TODO: Create a Firebase user

    private void createFirebaseUser(){

        String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
        String password = mConfirmPasswordView.getText().toString();
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                Log.d("Info:", "createUser onComplete " +task.isSuccessful());

                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d("Info:", "user creation failed");

                }
                }
        });



    }
```

Comment: I'm on mobile so it's hard to tell. Doesn't look like your createfirebaseuser function gets called anywhere if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: This was it. Thank you. I missed that part.

Comment: I know the feeling  Good luck